# Find in php special html tags macro

Tags: php

How can I do something like PHP macro in HTML page, for example:

```
<html>
    <head>        
    </head>    
    <body>
        blabla         
        <div>
            some html code
        </div>
        blabla      
    </body>
</html>
```

and when I use somthing like this {%}

```
<div>{%}</div>
```

to show me :

some html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing PHP and HTML which cannot (or precisely: shouldn't) be mixed.

PHP only output HTML.
HTML cannot execute PHP

you can however create a PHP file that outputs HTML like:

```
<?php
$variable = '<b>some html code</b>';
echo '<div>'.$variable.'</div>';
```

but all of this needs to be done within PHP file.

EDIT: I see the question title was updated a bit so here's my updated answer:
the HTML code from other page can be traversed by using Xpath: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: How on earth did you work out that *that* was the question?!

Comment: Years of answering trainee questions. ;)

Comment: `You're mixing PHP and HTML which cannot (or precisely: shouldn't) be mixed.` <- not sure how 100% this as this is a very standardised common practice - not that I'm for it, personally prefer building the page data with php to send to twig to handle, but eh, is just me

Comment: I'm speaking about current standard of keeping things separated. You shouldn't keep view and logic together. (as in MVC for example)

Comment: something i using php get content and str replace and it work

Comment: using php get content  from url to get code source and i use str replace

Comment: please see my updated answer. xpath is the way to go, preg_match could also work, but is more risky in terms of what gets matched.

Comment: @janmyszkier that's not a standard, that's a design pattern^